# 'autoposition' attribute not being applied between JsPanels

Tags: javascript, panel

I'm starting to use [JsPanel](https://jspanel.de/index.html) in a project at work and I have some doubts on why the 'autoposition' is not being applied between some panels.

I have 4 panels: A, B, C and D.

A panel:

```
jsPanel.create({
    id:          'A',
    theme:       'primary',
    headerTitle: 'A panel',
    position:    { my: 'left-top',
                   at: 'left-top',
                   offsetX: '0px',
                   offsetY: '0px',
                   autoposition: 'down'
                 },
    contentSize: '450 250',
    content:     '<p> Test test test</p>',
    callback: function () {
        this.content.style.padding = '20px';
    },
    onbeforeclose: function () {
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
});
```

B panel:

```
jsPanel.create({
    id:          'B',
    theme:       'primary',
    headerTitle: 'B panel',
    position:    { my: 'center-top',
                   at: 'center-top',
                   offsetX: '0px',
                   offsetY: '0px',
                   autoposition: 'down'
                 },
    contentSize: '450 250',
    content:     '<p> Test test test</p>',
    callback: function () {
        this.content.style.padding = '20px';
    },
    onbeforeclose: function () {
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
});
```

C panel:

```
jsPanel.create({
    id:          'C',
    theme:       'primary',
    headerTitle: 'C panel',
    position:    { my: 'right-top',
                   at: 'right-top',
                   offsetX: '0px',
                   offsetY: '0px',
                   autoposition: 'down'
                 },
    contentSize: '450 250',
    content:     '<p> Test test test</p>',
    callback: function () {
        this.content.style.padding = '20px';
    },
    onbeforeclose: function () {
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
});
```

D panel:

```
jsPanel.create({
    id:          'D',
    theme:       'primary',
    headerTitle: 'D panel',
    position:    { my: 'left-top',
                   at: 'left-bottom',
                   of: '#A',
                   autoposition: 'up'
                 },
    contentSize: '450 250',
    content:     '<p>Test test test</p>',
    callback: function () {
        this.content.style.padding = '20px';
    },
    onbeforeclose: function () {
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
});
```

Reading the [documentation of the 'position' option](https://jspanel.de/api.html#options/position), specifically the ['autoposition' attribute](https://jspanel.de/api.html#options/position/autoposition), says that you can set a value to add a gap between panels to prevent them from piling up on each other:

> 'down' for panels positioned using either 'left-top', 'center-top' or 'right-top' for both my: and at: setting autoposition to 'down' will automatically add a vertical offset downwards to each elmt in order to prevent them from piling up on each other. Removing a jsPanel will automatically reposition the remaining panel in the same stack.
>
> 'up' for panels positioned using either 'left-bottom', 'center-bottom' or 'right-bottom' for both my: and at: setting autoposition to 'up' will automatically add a vertical offset upwards to each elmt in order to prevent them from piling up on each other. Removing a jsPanel will automatically reposition the remaining panel in the same stack.

but for me it's not being applied. I've tried to remove the `autoposition` in *A* or *D* but no result.

[image: Panels]

So what am I doing wrong or what have I misunderstood?

Regards.

-- Edit 1:

I have achieved the separation adding:

```
offsetY: '8px',
```

to `panel D` but I think that this is not the correct solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was a misunderstanding with positions. Seeing [example number 5](https://jspanel.de/api.html#options/position/example-5) that adds panels one below the other the positions are:

```
my: 'right-top',
at: 'right-top',
```

and then you set:

```
autoposition: 'down',
```

So in panel D I had to change:

```
position:    { my: 'left-top',
               at: 'left-bottom',
               of: '#A',
               autoposition: 'up'
             },
```

to

```
position:    { my: 'left-top',
               at: 'left-top',
               of: '#A',
               autoposition: 'down',
               offsetY: 4px
             },
```

The `offsetY` is optional. By default **JsPanel** adds a *4px* separation but if you look on the image, the horizontal separation is *4px + 4px* so I add 4 extra pixels to match visually the horizontal separation with the vertically separation.

Regards!